# Very basic? C++/CLI problem

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I'm using VC++ 2010.

I'm getting error C2228. It says it must be a struct, class or unioun before .Text.

```
private: System::Void textBox1_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    using namespace std;
    for(int r=0; r>(sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])); r++){
        if (x[r][1].find(textBox1.Text) != string::npos){
            label1.Text = (label1.Text+x[r][1]);
            label2.Text = (label1.Text+x[r][2]);
        }
    }
}
```

It basically searches a 2D array and sees if anything matches what you've typed and displays it while you're typing, which is the main feature of the application I am making.
It errors on the if statement, the two statements after it twice and that's it, .Text is bringing up errors on all 5 attempts to read it, identical to the error I posted above.

Comment: Not enough information. You don't even give a line number. But something is wrong with `textBox1` or `label1`... one is not what you think it is. And, as an aside, I think you meant `label2` on the last content line.

Comment: is the member textBox1 defined? Are label1 & label2 defined?

Comment: Everything is defined, the line numbers are the three lines with text in them, I don't think it's very hard to find them, so I didn't bother to post them.

Comment: @Ashley: because it's not. It's C++/CLI, Microsoft's C++/.NET hybrid. It's not C++ because 1) WinForms aren't available in C++, and 2) the `^` references aren't valid in C++.

Comment: @Ashley Davies: It's not C++ because it's using .Net types and C++ is not a .Net language. Maybe it is a somewhat similar programming language called C++/CLI (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245196/c-urban-myths/2245851#2245851.

Comment: Apologies, I had no clue of that, bit misguiding as it says C++ on the project choice window. Thanks for telling me

Comment: @Ashley: What is the type of `x`, `std::string x[n][m];` or `array<String^, m>^`? You are comparing the size of STL Allocator which is a type of size_t with whatever `find()` returns. This is not good. Don't use STL code in a C++ Cli project. Probably you copy-pasted this from a real C++ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
using namespace std;

private: 
    System::Void textBox1_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        for(int r=0; r > (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0])); r++) {
            if (x[r][1].find(textBox1.Text) != string::npos){
            label1.Text = (label1.Text + x[r][1]);
            label2.Text = (label1.Text + x[r][2]);
            }
        }
    }
```

The using command should be at the highest level and the formatting is nicer like that. I hope that solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for helping, (edit) I fixed all the errors by putting it just below my preprocessor lines, but it still gives same errors.

Comment: Actually it is good that Asley is using namespace std only inside the function. From the looks of it the method is declared in the header and it wouldn't be a good idea to have using namespace std; in the header at file scope. At class scope it might be ok. In any case this is not why it doesn't work but rather the fact that she usesr . on the references rather than -> as she should

Comment: He*; On the other answer I changed them to -> but I had an error I don't actualy understand and then two saying the + sign didn't accept anything on the right side of it. I posted them on that question.

Answer (score 1):

You should use -> instead of .

Like this: textBox1->Text->ToString() or label1->Text

Comment: That fixed my .Text errors, but I'm getting these now: Error 1 error C2664: 'unsigned int std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::find(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &,unsigned int) const' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::String ^' to 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &'    And two about + not taking anything on the right side of it

Comment: @Ashley Davies The reson for that is that you are using STL and the STL types cannot work with managed types. You should probably use STL.Net instead. See here for an intro to STL.NET. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379600%28v=vs.80%29.aspx or here http://www.codeguru.com/columns/kate/article.php/c10297

Comment: @Ashley Davies Or use .NET containers instead (from System::Collections::Generic)